# Import error installing SciPy

Tags: python, windows, numpy, scipy, importerror

I've facing serious troubles in trying to install the SciPy package on Windows...

I keep getting this error:

> ImportError:
>       Importing the multiarray numpy extension module failed.  Most
>       likely you are trying to import a failed build of numpy.
>       If you're working with a numpy git repo, try `git clean -xdf` (removes all
>       files not under version control).  Otherwise reinstall numpy.
>
> ```
> Original error was: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
> ```

followed by this:

```
Command "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\...\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-xm76_hu7\\scipy\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-epfoebfp-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-xm76_hu7\scipy\
```

Really don't know how to solve this, I tried:

- Easy_install
- Upgrade Numpy
- Force reinstall Numpy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually installing SciPy on Windows through pip has a lot of troubles as there are dependencies that are required for you to compile which are known to be trouble on this operating system.

The best way that I've found to get them to work is to install pre-compiled wheels made specifically for Windows.  I've found that Christoph Gohlke's website of pre-compiled wheels is the best way to install packages on Windows.

http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

The SciPy wheel requires NumPy compiled under MKL through his website, but that's also available through him as well.

First install the NumPy + MKL wheel: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy

You need to make sure you choose the correct Python version and bit version for your Python.  You can see that in the file name of each wheel.  For example, `numpy‑1.13.1+mkl‑cp34‑cp34m‑win_amd64.whl` is for Python 3.4, 64 bit.

Download it, save it to your computer then use `pip` to install the wheel:

```
pip install numpy‑1.13.1+mkl‑cp34‑cp34m‑win_amd64.whl
```

This is assuming you are running `pip` in the same directory where you downloaded the wheel.  Change the filename to whatever version you downloaded in the above command.

Once you install that, then go ahead and install SciPy: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scipy.  Make sure you choose the correct Python version and bit version as well.

After this, it'll hopefully resolve any SciPy errors you have as it'll be based off of a working distribution of it.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you using a [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/):

```
mkdir .venv
cd .venv
virtualenv my_project
source my_project/bin/activate
```

And then install numpy

```
pip install numpy
```

Comment: Using a virtual environment doesn't escape trying to install scipy on Windows. Using pip to install scipy frequently gives errors. It's best to install a precompiled wheel if you want to use pip through Christoph Gohlke.

Comment: @rayryeng: You are right. Currently, there are no official binary release for Windows in [PyPi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/scipy). The Christoph Gohlke’s site is actually the reference according to the [SciPy documentation page](https://www.scipy.org/install.html).